# Is there a way to slowdown mysql query for lower cpu usage?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, cpu-usage

I am ordering INT rows by DESC on a table with 300k rows and selecting @rownum:=@rownum+1 to update the same row's RANK field.

It works perfectly but takes a long time. I can accept the longer time, but can i somewhat let it sleep to give some free space to CPU to make the other jobs?

Like putting sleep(0.25 sec) in a while(1>0) loop...

**UPDATE:**
SET @rownum=0;
update user u, (SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 as rank, id FROM user u order by score DESC) as bb SET u.rank=bb.rank WHERE u.id=bb.id

Comment: This sounds very misguided. It sounds like you approach to querying might be a problems as making an update to 300K rows should not take that long assuming you are using proper indexing. Can you add information on your query?

Comment: I have added my query to the question

Comment: Is there an index on the `score` column? What does the `explain` say for this query? I wouldn't be surprised if MySQL executed a query like this as a Cartesian product, but well this is not an operation you should be doing all the time anyway.

Comment: @Niels I couldn't make an EXPLAIN on UPDATE query, i think it currently does not exist on my mysql server (older version).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You can have some minor influence on priority with the `insert delayed` statement, by adding `low_priority` to an update, or by adding `high_priority` to a select. This only affects some queueing with table locks in storage engines using them. You cannot however have more granular control than that. It shouldn't be that way either, since the DBMS will balance itself internally, and one slow query should never make another query *MUCH* slower. If by 'other jobs' you mean other tasks on the same server, you could just `ionice` or `nice` the entire `mysqld` process.

Having answered the actual question, your query is probably this slow because it misses an index on the field you're sorting by, as such triggering `filesort` and `temporary` flags on the execution plan. Fixing that might make the whole point moot.

Comment: Eventhough i got that i can not get a YES answer, this is the closest answer by recommending ionice/nice.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably create a temp table with autoincrement ID to do this.  You could then `INSERT ... SELECT` the sorted values into the temp table to generate the rank sequence.  Then you could update the original table across a join.

Comment: Thanks, eventhough this did not work (i tried it after your answer), i will create a permanent table named user_rank and TRUNCATE, INSERT and i will query that table instead of "select rank from user". This returns almost instantly.

Comment: Yes, If you want to have permanent table that would work as well.  Not sure why a temp table wouldn't work for you though

Comment: i have to query "rank" values "any" time. This requires either a permanent table or a mass update from temptable to main user table (which locks user table for a long time)